# Can't load SQLite.Interop.dll when referencing a DLL containing System.Data.SQLite.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

When I follow the online method

> [Unable to Load SQLite.Interop.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091999/unable-to-load-sqlite-interop-dll)

, and modify the attribute of SQLite.Interop.dll  as copy.
I generate an A.dll and use another B.exe to reference this A.dll, but the project will not be automatically generated  SQLite.Interop.dll.
Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)

Answer (score 1):

**Use the library the way it's mean to, that is, through its NuGet package:**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Everything should go smoothly then.