# “Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies” running an application in Docker, but locally it works fine

Tags: docker, sqlite, dll, dockerfile, system.data.sqlite

## Introduction

There seems to be frequent issues with the `SQLite.Interop.dll` library. Just look at these other StackOverflow questions:

- [Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)
- [Visual Studio C# - SQLite.Interop.dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594837/visual-studio-c-sharp-sqlite-interop-dll-not-found)
- ["Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' error on client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778425/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll-error-on-client-machine)

I’ve gone through all of the above and more:

- I installed the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` NuGet package,
- I specified [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039244/3918095) elements in the `*.csproj`,
- I set `x64` instead of `Any CPU`,
- and so on

with no success. The key element is that the application runs just fine locally, but I need to make it run on **Docker**, and that’s where the problems start. The situation is that I’m working on a **.NET Core 3.1** console application with **Visual Studio 2022**. The application will be finally deployed on **AKS** ([Azure Kubernetes Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/)). Of course, first I need to make it work on the local installation of Docker in my development machine. **Building** the console application project on Visual Studio gives me no error and it runs fine from Visual Studio. **Building** its Docker image with the appropriate Dockerfile also gives no problems, but **running** the same image on Docker raises the following exception: `Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`. Currently, the project has the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` NuGet package installed and doesn’t have [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039244/3918095) elements in the `*.csproj`. The exception is raised by a project referenced by the one of the console application; this project both has the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` and `System.Data.SQLite` NuGet packages installed. The console application’s project has only the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` package installed (I already tried to install also the `System.Data.SQLite`, with no success). **All the projects, now, has the `System.Data.SQLite` NuGet package installed (to give it a try), which causes the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` to be installed as a dependency**.

## What I tried

I used the `Dockerfile` pre-assembled by Visual Studio 2022, which deals with all the various referenced projects:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj", "ProjectA/"]
COPY ["ProjectB/ProjectB.csproj", "ProjectB/"]
#COPY all the other referenced projects
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectA"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectA.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectA.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectA.dll"]
```

Since this Dockerfile is based on a **multi-stage build**, it has the following lines:

```
...
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
...
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
...
```

to first build the code, and then publish it. Given that `dotnet publish`, I decided to take a step back and be sure that, at least, I was able to publish the project myself, to narrow down the issue. I found that publishing it locally on a folder also gave me some problems, in particular the [NU1605](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605#issue-1) error, which was preventing me to end the process successfully. I resolved the issue using [what Microsoft suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605#solution-1). Now, **if I run the `.exe` located inside the publish destination folder, the application works as expected**.

It was time to finally make it a Docker image. The image building process went well, but then the `Unable...` error appeared at runtime. Reading online, to solve the `SQLite.Interop.dll` issue, they suggest to **move the `SQLite.Interop.dll` file directly in the `bin` folder**; in fact, originally, I found it lived inside the `bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\` folder, both in its `win-x86` and `win-x64` sub-directories. To “get rid” of this `runtimes` folder, I tried to publish the project locally on a folder, with the following settings:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**This in fact made the `SQLite.Interop.dll` appear directly inside the `bin` folder and got rid of the `runtimes` folder**. So, to obtain the same result with Docker, I modified the Dockerfile like this:

```
...
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build -r win-x64
...
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r win-x64
...
```

and now the `SQLite.Interop.dll` file appears directly also inside the `bin` folder in the Docker running container, so I thought everything was just fine at that time, but still I got the exception.

## One last thing

I found that running the application locally (not in Docker) without specifying the destination runtime (so, keeping the build process as `Any CPU` instead of `x64`), raised **no exceptions** (that is, keeping the `runtimes/` folder and the two `SQLite.Interop.dll` files inside of it, in the `win-x86` and `win-x64` sub-folders).

Comment: what happens if you run it locally using Docker Desktop? Do you get the same error?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio running it locally doesn’t cause the exception to appear.

Comment: so maybe you're trying to run windows containers on linux, or the opposite

Comment: @ThiagoCustodiono, everything is fine about that; AKS would complain about those kind of issues.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio my fault, even locally I get the same exception.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I updated the question with the right, current situation.

Comment: Can you indicate if you use Linux or Windows containers? Why do you specify the x64? AnyCPU is the same as x64 on a 64-bit machine. Can you post the relevant part of the Dockerfile? Can you post the relevant code of the project to repro the issue?

Comment: @Max I use Windows containers; I specify `x64` because of what I read online on other relevant SO posts, so I decided ti give it a try; I cannot post the relevant part of the code because it’ quite big; I update the question with the relevant part of the DOckerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to Linux containers.

Answer (score 2):

We have experienced the issue updating from System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.113.6 to 1.0.117.

Locally and in build pipeline everything works fine, but as soon as our app deployed in a docker container running mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-nanoserver-1809 image - application throws the named exception `Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found.`

I found this thread at sqlite forum which clarified the situation a bit: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/0c471ca86ae7a836

Quote from the forum:

> This actually seems to be caused by some extra dependencies in the
> latest version of SQLite.Interop.dll.
>
> Using dumpbin I compared the dependencies between version 1.0.113.7
> and 1.0.114.4 and these new dependencies were added:
>
> ```
> mscoree.dll
>          1801473F0 Import Address Table
>          180186090 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                       6F StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx
>                       71 StrongNameTokenFromAssembly
>                       62 StrongNameFreeBuffer
>                        F CorBindToRuntimeEx
>                       61 StrongNameErrorInfo
>
> WINTRUST.dll
>          1801473E0 Import Address Table
>          180186080 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                       82 WinVerifyTrust
> ```
>
> mscoree.dll is not available in in the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime image I was
> using. If I copy it in from a different image, SQLite.Interop.dll is
> loaded successfully

We ended up reverting back to version 1.0.113.6 as we didn't want to introduce extra complexity to docker image. I hope the issue with the latest System.Data.SQLite.Core will be resolved in one of the coming versions.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

To run a dotnet application (e.g. `dotnet test`) inside a windows docker container with the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` nuget package you can use the following docker file

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\nodejs"

# Install Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]

# Install .NET 6.0 for x86 (just change it to the platform you need)
RUN Invoke-WebRequest `
            -UseBasicParsing `
            -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 `
            -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1; `
        ./dotnet-install.ps1 `
            -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet' `
            -Channel 6.0 `
            -Architecture x86
```

Here is the releveant part of my csproj file:

```
   <ItemGroup>
      ...
      <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.117" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

### What worked for me

After switching to the [script](https://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/installing-dotnet.md) method, to install the .NET framework (and not using the binary) it worked for me.

Beforehand, like you, I tried a ton of different things!

#### What you can try

What might work is also to add the `PrivateAssets="none"` in the csproi. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll#60176344). After adding this to the csproj files I got a different error, because I must use a x86-dll in my project.

After installing .NET 6 x86 correctly, I reverted even this change in the csproj and it still worked!

#### What else

What I also tried, but was not necessary in the end, was Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library.

Quote from https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

> > All downloadable packages on this web page that do not include the word "static" in their file name require the appropriate version (e.g. 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017) of the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library, to be successfully installed on the target machine, prior to making use of the executables contained therein.

```
...
# Install Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; `
    Invoke-WebRequest "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe" -OutFile "vc_redist.x64.exe"; `
    Start-Process -filepath C:\vc_redist.x64.exe -ArgumentList "/install", "/passive", "/norestart" -Passthru | Wait-Process; '
    Remove-Item -Force vc_redist.x64.exe;
```

More information on *How-To* install .NET in a docker container can be found [at the dotnet-docker github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/installing-dotnet.md)

## TL/DR

Use `dotnet-install.ps1` in your dockerfile to install .NET and the SDK. Somehow, it does some magic, so that you can run dotnet apps which are using the `SQLite.Interop.dll` library (included via nuget)

Comment: Thanks - it works, but changes the docker image size from 333mb to 4.06GB (.NET 7 dotnet runtime, Server core 2022)

Comment: I was so happy that it finally worked, that I didn't check the size of the container. 
Anyhow, in my case I'm using it as a build environment on a build node and therefore the size doesn't matter. 

If my answer helped, an upvote for my ego would be nice :)

Comment: upvoted!
BTW in the end I went with downgrading System.Data.SQLite.Core to 1.0.113.7 - which worked and kept the docker image size low. I couldn't do this through Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." because this version of the Nuget package has been removed from the Nuget GUI, so did it through the .csproj file